# Pageok given by puppet instead of subdomain files hosted on godaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record, errordocument

I'm managing the e-commerce website for a retail store in Los Angeles, and use a subdomain hosted on GoDaddy as a fileserver to augment our Online Webstore CMS, which won't take large files (and honestly is an outdated and cumbersome system for managing files, but it's attached to our point of sale system, so the word on high is to make it work).

The trouble is that a week or two ago, files.abc.com stopped serving files publicly. Instead, abc.com is full of broken image links. Attempts to load any html files that exist in the root or to follow image urls makes the browser load a white page which says pageok with the following source code:

```
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>
```

FileZilla has no problem accessing these files with my ftp credentials, but browsers can't get it.

While researching an answer, I saw someone who might have had the  [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461361/does-rails-web-server-block-http-301-from-godaddy)  was referred to Server Fault, but I found no questions under "pageok". I searched for general subdomain issues with goDaddy and found  [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/226899/move-primary-domain-hosting-from-godaddy-but-keep-email-subdomains-there-w-n)  article,

so I tried to compare our set-ups to figure out if it's a problem with the DNS, but I'm in over my head, perhaps.

GoDaddy says nameservers are:

```
@ (Informational) ns51.domaincontrol.com (Informational) 
@ (Informational) ns52.domaincontrol.com (Informational)
```

In this context, what does "informational" indicate? Other DNS info:

For my a records, "*" and "@" map to 209.117.231.3
"blog", "files", and "livechat" map to 50.63.45.1, where you can see the pageok error.

I have the following cname records:

e
email
ftp
imap
mail
mobilemail
pda
pop
smtp
webmail
www

Comment: So the files are still there in FTP, but won't load via HTTP?  This sounds like GoDaddy's problem, not yours..  Googling `godaddy pageok` is turning up a lot of results with the same issue.  Sounds like it's some kind of problem with their account management system?

Comment: I've been emailing goDaddy support and have posted on their help boards and after two weeks it still hasn't been resolved, so I guess my question becomes how to be sure I'm correctly changing all the DNS information so that there is no downtime for the site if I move all the files to be served by the subdomain to dreamhost. Since the domain was registered with godaddy, and the main site is hosted by the CMS, would I change the nameservers to dreamhost and then point to the IP currently listed in goDaddy's DNS?

Comment: Were you planning on moving DNS as well?

Answer (score 0):

It may sound too late for this one. But just in case someone else experiences it, here's how I get it through:

1. Open your account on GoDaddy and check the server IP
2. Do a traceroute on your domain. you can use http://network-tools.com or something similar other than your own route.
3. If the ip's do not match, update your DNS entry for that domain and use the server IP specified on your GD account.
4. Let your DNS propagate, which may take some time, and check the route again.

If it fails, continue looking for a solution.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error always means that the Godaddy server your site is currently pointed to is not configured to host your site. Here are likely causes, in order of likelihood:

- Hosting was recently set up, and will take a few hours to be ready.
- Your DNS was rightfully changed and has not propagated to the new, correct location yet. Sometimes servers will just change IP addresses and Godaddy will automatically switch you with them, but it could take time to propagate.
- You purchased your hosting and pointed your domain to it but never actually set the site up within that hosting.
- Something else has gone wrong within Godaddy's system

I have a full [writeup of the pageok error](https://pagecrafter.com/pageok-hosting-error-with-godaddy/) and solutions available.

If the error has been up for less than 24 hours, I generally recommend waiting. Otherwise, I would check your A record over at [whatsmydns.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) and verify that it is the same one associated with your hosting account. If you're all set there and it's been more than 24 hours, I recommend reaching out to Godaddy support.